# How to bound $\int_{1}^x \frac{\sin([t])}t\,\mathrm dt$?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, improper-integrals, ceiling-and-floor-functions

When I try to do some exercises, the following question raises.

How to bound $\displaystyle\int_{1}^x \dfrac{\sin(\lfloor t\rfloor)}{t}dt$ by a good upper bound than $\ln x$?

$\ln x$ is the trivial as
$$\left|\displaystyle\int_{1}^x \dfrac{\sin(\lfloor t\rfloor)}{t}dt\right| \leq \int_{1}^x \dfrac{1}{t}dt = \ln x.$$

Answer (score 4):

Actually the limit (as $x\to\infty$) **exists**. We may write $\int_1^x=\int_1^{\lfloor x\rfloor}+\int_{\lfloor x\rfloor}^x$ and see that the second integral tends to $0$ as $x\to\infty$, and the first integral (after $\int_1^n=\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\int_k^{k+1}$) is $$\sum_{k=1}^{\lfloor x\rfloor-1}\log\frac{k+1}{k}\ \sin k,$$ which has a finite limit (as $x\to\infty$) by [Dirichlet's test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet%27s_test).